# How can I add a variable/function every time a variable reaches a certain number?

Tags: javascript

So I created this small "game" based off of a small intro youtube series about a year ago and I have recently found my old program and was wondering how I expand it. One of my ideas was that there is a variable called "badcube" and if the player was to touch it, it resets the game/score. I was wondering how I would set it up so that every 5 points or so it adds an Identical variable to bad cube making the game harder.

EDIT/UPDATE: so I added some lines based on the response from Jared Bledsoe, 
I added the variable `var cubebadary = [];` and I added the if statement:`if (score % 5 == 0){cubebadary.push(new cubebad());}` I added this as you will se in the posted code under the function update. but when I try to run it through a simple html page I check the console and It comes with the error:
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHThV.png)
what does this mean and how do I chage/fix this?

The Program:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("maincanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var keys = [];
var width = 1920,
height = 1080,
speed = 10;
var score = 0;
var player = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  width: 20,
  height: 20
};
var cubegood = {
  x: Math.random() * (width - 10),
  y: Math.random() * (height - 10),
  width: 10,
  height: 10
};
var cubebad = {
  x: Math.random() * (width - 20),
  y: Math.random() * (height - 20),
  width: 20,
  height: 20
};
var cubebadary= [];
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  keys[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  delete keys[e.keyCode];
}, false);
/*
up - 38
down - 40
left - 37
right - 39
*/
function game() {
  update();
  render();
}
function update() {
  if (keys[38]) player.y -= speed;
  if (keys[40]) player.y += speed;
  if (keys[37]) player.x -= speed;
  if (keys[39]) player.x += speed;
  if (player.x < 0) player.x = 0;
  if (player.x >= width - player.width) player.x = width - player.width;
  if (player.y < 0) player.y = 0;
  if (player.y >= height - player.height) player.y = height - player.height;
  if (collision(player, cubegood)) processgood();
  if (collision(player, cubebad)) processbad();
  if (score & 5 == 0)
  {
       cubebadary.push(new cubebad());
  }
}
function render() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)
  context.fillStyle = "blue";
  context.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
  context.fillStyle = "red";
  context.fillRect(cubegood.x, cubegood.y, cubegood.width, cubegood.height);
  context.fillStyle = "black"
  context.fillRect(cubebad.x, cubebad.y, cubebad.width, cubebad.height);  
  context.font = "bold 30px helvetica";
  context.fillText(score, 30, 30);
}
function processgood(){
  score++;
  cubegood.x = Math.random() * (width-10);
  cubegood.y = Math.random() * (height-10);
}
function processbad(){
  location.reload(true);
}
function collision(first, second) {
  return !(first.x > second.x + second.width || 
           first.x + first.width < second.x || 
           first.y > second.y + second.height || 
           first.y + first.height < second.y);
}
setInterval(function() {
  game();
}, 1000 / 30);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you just need to make a `badCubeArr` (name it what you want) -- pretty much just a array holding multiple "cubeBad" objects with different coords

Comment: do you mean certain instead of sertain?

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need an array to store all of the new enemies.

```
var enemies = [];
```

Then, when you want to create a new enemy:

```
enemies.push(new cubebad());
```

To view this in a working demo, feel free to visit a project I'm working on that happens to deal with lots of enemies (asteroids) here - http://asteroidio.bitballoon.com/

Starting at line 333 on that game, you can see the Asteroid object I have which acts as a template for creating all asteroids. Then, once the game initiates I use:

```
for (let i=0; i<foodValue; i++) {
    asteroids[i] = new Asteroids;
}
```

Which creates a few hundred asteroids, and puts them into an array.